# No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document

Tags: html, xml, eclipse, xsd

I have a code like this, where dokument is my main element. I have my own namespace: xmlns="http://wlasna_przestrzen.nazw.pl"
And I would like to use another namespace only to putting screens via html

```
<dokument 
xmlns="http://wlasna_przestrzen.nazw.pl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://wlasna_przestrzen.nazw.pl/ albumy.xsd"
xmlns:JĘZYK_HTML="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
```

I have a file xsd which contains:

```
<xsd:schema 
xmlns:nasza_przestrzeń="http://wlasna_przestrzen.nazw.pl"
targetNamespace="http://wlasna_przestrzen.nazw.pl" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" >
```

And my question is why I have an error like this:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `window -> Preferences , then XML -> XML Files -> Validation` then set

`Indicate when no grammar is specified` to `ignore`