# soapui - warning - No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, soapui

In my soapui xml, following are the first 2 lines (with whitespace added for legibility).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-project name="Project_sample" 
  resourceRoot="${projectDir}" 
  soapui-version="3.6.1" 
  abortOnError="false" 
  runType="SEQUENTIAL" 
  defaultScriptLanguage="Groovy" 
  xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
  <con:settings>
    <con:setting id = "com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.tools.soapui.TestRunnerAction@values-local" 
  ><![CDATA[<xml-fragment
     xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">  
......................  
....................... goes on
```

I have already checked the following urls

[No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551783/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document)

[No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203898/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document)

[Bogus Eclipse warning for web.xml: "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322155/bogus-eclipse-warning-for-web-xml-no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-d)

[No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document in a taglib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742753/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document-in-a-taglib)

[How to fix Eclipse validation error "No grammar constraints detected for the document"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833057/how-to-fix-eclipse-validation-error-no-grammar-constraints-detected-for-the-doc)

---

But I dont like to modify configurations in Eclipse (such as Windows->pref->xml->validation->Grammar->Ignore

I would like to edit the xml config - probably in the above 2 lines. Is it possible to remove this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of googling, it seems like there is no Schema file for those soapui config files.

I understand that you merely want to get rid of the Eclipse warning but without modifying any Eclipse settings. Well, here's a hack:

Change your XML header to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE soapui-project>
<con:soapui-project name="Project_sample" resourceRoot="${projectDir}" ...>
```

This "micro doctype" does not do any validation but stops Eclipse from saying there is no schema.

Comment: I am getting 'schema compliance' error after adding the above line. I am checking this now

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a XSD file, which I found here:
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/parsing-soapui-project-file/td-p/1492

However that is from 2008 and for a very old SoapUI versions.
The current version's file do not match this.

But, it shows that a) There is a XSD, b) the company (currently SmartBear) is willing to give it away. So you may ask at their support.

Also, you might want to look through the SoapUI app files. It might contain this XSD.